# Is there any way to know SQL server agent job status?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job

I am using SQL server 2008 R2 and I am wondering if there is a way to know SQL server agent job status (running/stopped) with some query. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a system stored procedure sp_help_job. This returns information on the job, its steps, schedules and servers. For example

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @Job_name = 'The name of the job'
```